# Return and execute a method by a method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, return, action

I have my **MainClass** and **MethodFinder** classes. I want to obtain the method name to be run in Main via **MethodFinder** and execute it.

How can I do that?

What I want is a class with a method that returns **Method1** or **Method2** (based on some criteria) which then can be run in **MainClass**'s **MainMethod**!

```
public MainClass
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var methodFinder = new MethodFinder();
        var method = methodFinder.Find();

        // Execute method
    }

    private void Method1(){}
    private void Method2(){}
}
```

Comment: What is `.Find()` returning? Seems like either a `string` or `MethodInfo`

Comment: What is `MethodFinder`? Does it already exist or do you want to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) type in this situation, as long as the methods have the same signature. If your method took parameters, you could use [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx). If it returned a value, you could use [`Func<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public Action Find(SomeType someParameter)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        return new Action(() => Method1());
    }
    else
    {
        return new Action(() => Method2());
    }
}
```

Note though this method smells like a case where you might want to use [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to achieve your goals, or possibly [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Thank you so much Eric. Exactly, I smell a bad design here too!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, or use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx) to be more dynamic.

```
public class MethodFinder
{
    public delegate void MethodSignature();

    //these can live whereever and even be passed in
    private static void Method1() => Debug.WriteLine("Method1 executed");
    private static void Method2() => Debug.WriteLine("Method2 executed");

    //maintain an array of possibilities or soemthing.
    //perhaps use reflection instead
    private MethodSignature[] methods = new MethodSignature[] { Method1, Method2 };

    public MethodSignature FindByName(string methodName) 
        => (from m in methods
            where m.Method.Name == methodName
            select m).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Usage:

```
var methodFinder = new MethodFinder();
var method = methodFinder.FindByName("Method2");
method(); //output: "Method2 executed"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as well.